# Saving HTML contents throws Data too long for column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am saving HTML contents in "html_contents(TEXT)" column in a table called mobile_apps. 
When i try to save it, i get the following error

Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'html_contents' at row 1: UPDATE `mobile_apps` SET `html_contents` = `<p>HTML contents</p>`

Comment: Try change column type to TEXT or LONGTEXT. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: i used the limit `change_column :mobile_apps, :html_contents, :text, :limit => 4294967295`, i am able to save.Thanks

Comment: Whenever you have huge amounts of data to save in a database field, it's worth asking "Should this actually be saved in a file?".  A lot of the time people will actually **upload** a file and then just shove all of the file data in the database.  This is bad because it will bloat out your database like crazy, making for longer backups and greater overhead.  If you want to analyse the contents of the field in an sql query then it needs to be data.  if you just need to store and retrieve it think about files, with just the filename, or some reference to the file, stored in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try to customize the length of your varchar column (it's always a good practice):

```
#migration
...
t.string :html_contents, :limit => 500 # <-change to the max length of your field
...
```